# I have Tracelog file which contained some id and bytes. How can i put them in table in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

trace file have ID and bytes and with the time like :

```
0.516516 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 04
0.516517 ID2 00 08 07 06 05 05
0.516518 ID3 00 08 07 06 05 06
0.516519 ID4 00 08 07 06 05 07
0.516520 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 08
```

so on...

I want to make table like ID1 message and time data will come toghether
like

```
0.516516 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 04
0.516520 ID1 00 08 07 06 06 08
```

So need idea how to implemented I tried with list of all things but didn't find help so other than list any other way to do?

I want to check data for all time with related like:
 0.516516 ID1 value is 00 08 07 06 05 04 and at time 0.516520 ID1 value is 00 08 07 06 06 04 i want to check my 5 byte is it increment properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to take values from either a file or from some variable and split them based on endline char which will give you a nice list line by line and then you can simply check if `ID1` in current string just append to my output and you are done. you can do the same for rest of the IDs as well.

Here is the sample code to Filter `ID1` rows from given data.

```
import re

myValues = """0.516516 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 04\n
0.516517 ID2 00 08 07 06 05 05\n
0.516518 ID3 00 08 07 06 05 06\n
0.516519 ID4 00 08 07 06 05 07\n
0.516520 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 08"""

#get IDs and init IDs dictionary
outs = {}
myIDs = set(re.findall(r'ID\d',myValues))
for ID in myIDs: # iterate for each id and file related date in myValues variable
    outs[ID] = []

for ID in myIDs: # iterate for each id and file related date in myValues variable
    valuesList = myValues.split("\n")
    for values in valuesList :
        if ID in values:
            outs[ID].append(values)
for out_  in outs:
    lengthOfValues = len(outs[out_])
    count = 0
    while count+1 < lengthOfValues:
            bytes1 = int("".join(outs[out_][count].split(out_)[1].split(" ")))
            bytes2 = int("".join(outs[out_][count+1].split(out_)[1].split(" ")))
            time1 = float("".join(outs[out_][count].split(out_)[0].split(" ")))
            time2 = float("".join(outs[out_][count + 1].split(out_)[0].split(" ")))
            print("{0} Bytes Increment from {1} to {2} i.e = ".format(out_,outs[out_][count].split(out_)[1],outs[out_][count+1].split(out_)[1] ), bytes2-bytes1)
            print("{0} Time Increment from {1} to {2} i.e  = ".format(out_,outs[out_][count].split(out_)[0],outs[out_][count+1].split(out_)[0]), bytes2 - bytes1)
            count+=1
```

**Output :**

```
ID1 Bytes Increment from  00 08 07 06 05 04 to  00 08 07 06 05 08 i.e =  4
ID1 Time Increment from 0.516516  to 0.516520  i.e  =  4
```

note : This implementation is here just to give you an idea to do comparison.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to do  only for ID1 but also other will be there like ID2, ID3.. so i am not sure how to do by making a table for all id or do other way

Comment: if your data is in text from you can extract all the ids from data and the print data accordingly using above approach is more simple i believe.

Comment: i just don't want to print i want to do more further with is like I have to check the data for all time and with specific id

Comment: I can help you more if you can update your question with specific requirement , as you have mentioned that you want to do further analysis on data . if you can add details about the output you want that will help us solve it for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can do this efficiently with `pandas` in a couple of lines:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""0.516516 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 04
0.516517 ID2 00 08 07 06 05 05
0.516518 ID3 00 08 07 06 05 06
0.516519 ID4 00 08 07 06 05 07
0.516520 ID1 00 08 07 06 05 08
""")

# read file, replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)

# sort by second column, write to csv
df.sort_values(1).to_csv(header=False, index=False, sep=' ')
```